# MAUI How to bind an ObservableCollection to a Grid?

Tags: maui

I have been able bind a Grid (size 2x2) to an ObservableCollection (size 4) but the code has a lot of duplication has each cell is manually binded to an index of the collection.

I need to increase the size of the grit to 7x7 so I would prefer a better way to do that. I've looked at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview

but dataTemplate seems to work on CollectionView not a Grid and the ContentView need binding for each Parameter which does not reduce complexity much.

**Does anyone has an idea / suggestion to improve this?**

**TestPage**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Maui.Views.TestPage"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Maui.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:TestPageViewModel"
             Title="TestMap">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Frame Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="0" 
               BackgroundColor="Blue">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Persons[0].Name}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Persons[0].Age}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Persons[0].Location}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="1" 
               BackgroundColor="Red">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Persons[1].Name}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Persons[1].Age}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Persons[1].Location}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0" 
               BackgroundColor="Green">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Persons[2].Name}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Persons[2].Age}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Persons[2].Location}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Frame Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="1" 
               BackgroundColor="Yellow">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Persons[3].Name}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Persons[3].Age}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Persons[3].Location}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>  
</ContentPage>
```

**TestPageViewModel**

```cs
public partial class TestPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public TestPageViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person { Name="John", Age=21, Location="US" },
            new Person { Name="Harry", Age=45, Location="Ireland" },
            new Person { Name="Robert", Age=32, Location="France" },
            new Person { Name="Juan", Age=68, Location="Spain" },
        };
    }
}
```

**Model**

```cs
public partial class Person : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string name;
    [ObservableProperty]
    public int age;
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string location;
}
```

Comment: Grid is not really designed to work like you want.  I would either try using a CollectionView with a grid layout, or you could use a Grid with a custom control that encapsulates your Frame.  Then you would only need to bind each element of the collection to the control, instead of binding each individual property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Grid` doesn't support binding to collections for dynamic population, neither by exposing an `ItemsSource` property nor by using `BindableLayout.ItemsSource`, all you're left with is using another type of layout for the collection, such as a `VerticalStackLayout`, `FlexibleLayout` or a `CollectionView` *(I recommend avoiding `ListView` for this)* and then using a `Grid` inside of the `DataTemplate` for each row.

In your case I recommend using the [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid), because it allows different layout styles, such as a Grid with two columns *(which seems to be what you're trying to achieve based on your code)*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Maui.Views.TestPage"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Maui.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:TestPageViewModel"
             Title="TestMap">

    <CollectionView
        ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
        ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2">

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Person">
                <controls:PersonView Person="{Binding .}"/>

                <!-- OR -->
                <!--
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="Green">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Age}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Location}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
                -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks Julian, the problem of collection view for my use case is that I want a fixed grid of size 7x7. It's less "hardcoded" binding but it will be harder to keep the size and order.

Comment: Then you can add 49 items to your collection, order them accordingly and use `ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 7"`. Just an idea 

Comment: It's an idea to investigate indeed. Do you know how the items are allocated to a column? Is this per row, column or something else?

Comment: AFAIK, the columns are filled row-by-row, starting from the top-left to the bottom-right. So item 0 would be at the top-left corner and item 6 at the top-right corner, item 43 at the bottom-left and item 49 at the bottom-right.

Comment: I tried and it's populated row-by-row. Your answer combined with mine is the best solution as all duplication is removed and there is dynamic population.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jason, I followed your advice and I have created a custom view. There are still some duplicate code but it's much more manageable now and less error prone.

I'm posting my code here for future dev who might need this. Updvote if it helped you :D

**PersonView**

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Maui.Controls.PersonView"
             x:Name="this">
    <Frame BindingContext="{x:Reference this}"
           BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Person.Name}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Person.Age}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Person.Location}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

```cs
public partial class PersonView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty PersonProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Person), typeof(Person), typeof(PersonView), new Person());
    public Person Person
    {
        get => (Person)GetValue(PersonView.PersonProperty);
        set => SetValue(PersonView.PersonProperty, value);
    }
    public PersonView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Test Page**

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Maui.Views.TestPage"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Maui.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:TestPageViewModel"
             Title="TestMap"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Maui.Controls">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <controls:PersonView Person="{Binding Persons[0]}" BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <controls:PersonView Person="{Binding Persons[1]}" BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
        <controls:PersonView Person="{Binding Persons[2]}" BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
        <controls:PersonView Person="{Binding Persons[3]}" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>  
</ContentPage>
```

**TestPageViewModel**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using Maui.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Maui.ViewModels;

public partial class TestPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public TestPageViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person { Name="John", Age=21, Location="US" },
            new Person { Name="Harry", Age=45, Location="Ireland" },
            new Person { Name="Robert", Age=32, Location="France" },
            new Person { Name="Juan", Age=68, Location="Spain" },
        };
    }
}
```

**Model**

```cs
public partial class Person : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string name;
    [ObservableProperty]
    public int age;
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string location;
}
```

Comment: This seems like an improvement, but there's still no dynamic population.

Comment: Indeed but the grid 7x7 is fixed and the items have an order. I'll probably change the ObversableCollection to an 2D array to make it easier...but I'm not sure if it's  type that is observable...I'll do some tests :D